# Confused about photodiode current

Tags: voltage, current, diodes, photodiode

I am confused about the photodiode current voltage diagram.

[image]

According to this diagram the current at zero bias is down->reverse current.How is that even possible?

At photovoltaic mode isnt the current forward?

Comment: Photocurrent is in the direction to cause the diode to conduct.

Comment: Where does the diagram come from? It looks like the three curves represent different optical conditions, but the context would be useful to confirm that.

Comment: *light* tends to bring the anode *voltage* more positive than cathode. Lower rightmost area of your graph.

Comment: Yes the three curves do represent different optical conditions.

Comment: So is it truely reverse current and this image aint wrong?

Comment: Photodiode current caused by light is a reverse current.

Comment: @MissMulan There's a nice overview [here](https://wp.optics.arizona.edu/mnofziger/wp-content/uploads/sites/31/2016/08/Detectors.pdf) that is well worth reading.

Comment: Perhaps will be also helpfull   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode

Answer (score 3):

> According to this diagram the current at zero bias is down->reverse
> current.How is that even possible?

First you must understand that this graph shows what happens when an external voltage is applied across the photodiode. By convention, when voltage is applied across a component any current flowing into it is considered positive, while current coming out of it (back into the voltage source) is negative.

In your graph P0 represents the photodiode with no light on it, so it is not generating any current and the curve looks like a standard diode (current passes through zero at zero applied voltage).

P1 and P2 show the results at two different light levels. In these cases the diode *is* generating a current, which appears as a negative value because it is coming *out* of the diode, not going into it. As forward bias voltage increases the 'regular' diode current increases exponentially, consuming the 'negative' photocurrent and (when bias voltage is high enough) making the external current become positive.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fusUg5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So it isnt reverse current?

Comment: It's 'reverse' current relative to the current supplied by the voltage source. The 'reverse' current shown in your graph is forward current from the photodiode's point of view (ie. it is supplying the current, not consuming it). In photovoltaic mode it would be forward current because then the photodiode _is_ the voltage source.

Answer (score 1):

As the light intensity increases there is increased photocurrent.

As can be seen from the graph this causes a voltage to exist across the diode at zero current coming from the pins of the device.

If the diode is biased in reverse the photo-current acts as increased leakage current, ie it tends to bring the voltage towards zero. (and ultimately to a positive value if allowed).

Photo-current is in the direction to cause the diode to conduct. It can be modeled as a current generator in parallel with a conventional diode.